# how to send a value via tcp in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sockets, tcp

I am developing rails app and following are the things that i have done and i need to do.

1. I am using rails for iphone app and i have an api for sending the values to the server.
2. When a user sends the value to the server, the value has to be stored in db and i need to show the values to the other user.
3. The other user should listen to the tcp server and the value should be received by that user.
4. I have read few examples from https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-rubysocks/l-rubysocks-a4.pdf and few other examples but i do not know how to proceed.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use plain http (or https) to communicate with iphone app.